# How to create a basic angularjs page for REST json data?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to create a basic webpage that shows data retrieved by `http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting`.

The json output is:

```
{"id":2273,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

I'm using the following html page:

```
<body ng-app="hello">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Greeting</h1>
        <div ng-controller="home" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
            <p>The Id is: {{greeting.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is: {{greeting.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/hello.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the hello.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('hello', []);

myApp.controller('home', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = {};

    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
}]);
```

Result: the placeholders `greeting.id/content` are not resolved. What might be wrong here?

Comment: if, just above the http block, you write:
`$scope.greeting = {"id": "test", "content": "test2"};`
you can check to see whether it's an issue with the $http request -- is it?

Comment: @brendan yes in this case everything works as expected.

Comment: Ok.  So what if instead of `$scope.greeting = data;`, just `console.log(data);` inside the $http?  Sorry, if you've already walked through all this, but it might isolate the issue better for us reading

Comment: I'm getting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header missing` on execution of the get request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't inject `$http` service.

```
myApp.controller('home', ['$scope, $http', function($scope, $http) {...}]);
```

**EDIT**

It is also worth to metnion what cverb said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31879507/1937797). In Angular 1.4 you should replace `.success()` with `.then()`, because `.success` is deprecated.

Now usage should be:

```
$http.get(url).then(
  function(data){
     //success callback
  }, 
  function(){
     //error callback
  });
);
```

Comment: Hm, now the placeholders are gone, *but* I still don't see any data displayed. Just blank.

Comment: As a general note, if you see your placeholders, then angular has suffered an error that you can check in the browser's js console.

Comment: console log to see what you get in the callback function ... check your console

Comment: In the console I can see `cross origin blocked`: Missing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Response

Comment: @membersound, It happens probably because external server doesn't allow cross origin requests. Search about this problem and you will find explanation better than I can give you ;)

Comment: @membersound, for example if you will try with that url, you will not get an error: `http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two`

Comment: Great, that works, and thanks for the `jsontest` url which is very nice for testing! So it's probably a server issue from the spring resource.

Answer (score 0):

change your $http call to following. You have also not injected $http in your controller.

```
 $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.greeting = data.data;
        });
```

Comment: Did not change anything.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: There is no nested `data` in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.success()` with `.then()`, the `.success()` method is deprecated and does not work in the same way as a normal promise.

If you wish to keep using it, you can just use it like this.

```
 $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
```

Also see the documentation of [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).